# Generic Service Connection in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, pipeline, gcloud

I am pretty new to Devops and I am trying to make a connection with the GCP. While creating the generic connection, what url do I have to provide? should it be the api endpoint? or the auth token url.
I am trying to connect with Bigquery api, and I am also confused about how should I authenticate?
Is there also any other way? I could not find any single blog that helps to  InvokeRestApi task to the GCP alongwith the authentication.

Thanks for helping:)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEDZO.png)

I tried with the gcloud shell in Azure but I am not sure how can I get the api response back from gcloud script.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Generic Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#generic-service-connection) and know about parameter and Description.

The `url` is the url of your service(e.g:https://gcr.io/PROJECT_ID).

The `Token Key` generated in the path of GCP:

**Service account->create service account->create key**